# Setting JSON key in appsettings from AzureDevOps Replace Tokens

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm struggling with using Replace Tokens Task in Azure Devops to send a variable to my appsettings.json file in a Blazor server app.

In `appsettings`, I have this:

```
{
  "version": "#{versionNumber}#"
}
```

In Azure DevOps, I set the following variable:

```
versionNumber: '$(version.Major).$(version.Minor).$(version.Revision)'
```

My ReplaceToken task is:

```
- task: replaceToken@3
  displayName: "Replacing version in appsettings"
  inputs:
    targetFiles: '**/*.appsettings.json'
    encoding: 'auto'
    writeBOM: true
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: false
    tokenPrefix: '#{'
    tokenSuffix: '}#'
    useLegacyPattern: false
    enableTelemetry: true,
    verbosity: detailed
```

However, in the build pipeline I see:

```
replaced 0 tokens out of 0 in 0 file(s) in 1.17 seconds
```

Any assistance on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your target files has `*.Appsettings.json`, what's the actual filename you are trying to update? Should it really have that `*. ` in it?

Comment: What's the working directory? Try setting something like `rootDirectory: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)` to ensure the right files are scanned. The default working directory may not be what you expect it to be.

Comment: according to their documentation, **/*.xyz is correct from what I can tell. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens

Comment: where would I do that? in this task or elsewhere in the pipeline?

Comment: The output indicates it didn't find any files, so that's what I'd look at first.

Comment: You set it in the task. The default working directory is dictates by the kind of job that's running and the tasks default. Some tasks define a working directory, others leave it to the agent to choose based on the job type. My recommendation: be explicit.

Comment: The rootDirectory property was guessed from the UI screenshot on their marketplace pages. On my phone now and can't build a quick test to verify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Setting JSON key in appsettings from AzureDevOps Replace Tokens

That because you are missing the parameter **Root directory** in that task, the base directory for searching files. If not specified the default working directory will be used.

Since you do not specify the Root directory in the task, it will use the default working directory, like `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`.

However, you specify the `targetFiles` with `**/*.appsettings.json`, if the `appsettings.json` file does not happen to be in a subfolder of the default folder, then you will encounter the same issue as you.

So, to resolve this issue, we need to specify the Root directory. You could use the Classic mode to select the file by the Browse Root Directory:

[image]

Then we could get the YAML by the View YAML option.

And test with sample, it works fine on my side:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this. I did get this working last night and it was a root directory problem. It was looking in the wrong folders without specifying the appropriate path.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your replaceToken task configuration expects a '}#' suffix, but that you may be missing the trailing # in your appsettings file.

Comment: I double checked, I do have a trailing # in appsettings json. Mistake on this post. Corrected original post.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Leo Liu's point about the directory not being specified, keep in mind that in YAML pipelines, `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` is not the same for releases as it is for Classic pipelines, and `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` is used instead. I've gotten into a lot of trouble with this one before. In your case, where looking to diagnose this, I'd add two steps to your build:

```
  - powershell: |
      Get-ChildItem $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\appSettings.json -Recurse
  - powershell: |
      Get-ChildItem $(Pipeline.Workspace)\appSettings.json -Recurse
```

If that's not revealing, take the `\appSettings.json` off those steps and inspect the entire result, if needed.